# A specific input tag was doubled the output

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to ask about my problem with my output.

I want to stop a specific refresh looping in a specific field text tag which my search text bar has doubled when a specific div is refresh.

I've used AJAX as a refresher in a specific div which named "refreshData" where I want to only refresh my table output.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cardview') or die ("could not connect to database");

 $con=  mysqli_query($conn, "select * from cardprocess");
   ?>

<style>
body {
background-color: #93B0B0;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

input[name=submit] {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-size: 16px;
}
th {
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-size: 19px;
}
td {
   background-color: white;
font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-size: 15px;
}
label {
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-size: 34px;
    }
</style>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search"> //Search Box in an outside div
    <div id = "refreshData">
<center>
<p>

      <div class= "caption">
      <h1>View Entry</h1>

<table width="50%" border="3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">   

                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>TIMESTAMP</th>
                    <th>CURRENT LOCATION</th>
                    <th>STATUS</th> 
            </tr>
            <tbody id = "table">

        <?php

             while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($con))
             {

                 ?>[enter image description here][1]
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['ID'] . "          ";?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Name'] . "        "; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['TimestampNow'] . "        " ; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Current'] . "        " ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Status'] . "         " ;?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php

             }
             ?>
         </tbody>
             </table>
            </div>

</p>
<a href = "main2.php"> <input type = "button" name= "submit" value = "BACK"></a>

</center>
</div>

<script src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> //this is my refresher in an table only
    setInterval(function(){
   $('#refreshData').load('view.php');
}, 4000) 
    </script>
    <script> //codes for filtering search that will show in an table
        var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Write a new php file which will only return the table values as JSON. Then call that file via AJAX and get the JSON then after parsing JSON values update the table rows

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the same page for refresh data that's why its update same data twice.

Do one thing make another PHP function and use only particular table data.
Like.
Result.php

```
<php
      $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cardview') or die ("could not connect to database");
      $con = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from cardprocess");
?>
<center>
<p>

      <div class= "caption">
      <h1>View Entry</h1>

<table width="50%" border="3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">   

                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>TIMESTAMP</th>
                    <th>CURRENT LOCATION</th>
                    <th>STATUS</th> 
            </tr>
            <tbody id = "table">

        <?php

             while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($con))
             {

                 ?>[enter image description here][1]
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['ID'] . "          ";?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Name'] . "        "; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['TimestampNow'] . "        " ; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Current'] . "        " ;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Status'] . "         " ;?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php

             }
             ?>
         </tbody>
             </table>
            </div>

</p>
<a href = "main2.php"> <input type = "button" name= "submit" value = "BACK"></a>

</center>
```

and update

```
    <script> //this is my refresher in an table only
    setInterval(function(){
   $('#refreshData').load('view.php');
}, 4000) 
    </script>
```

to

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
   $('#refreshData').load('Result.php');
}, 4000) 
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it seems that my search bar function doesnt work and if i put on the results.php, i cannot type there because it automatic reloads.